# Dynamic views with Codeigniter or templates or partial views

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

How can I load views of my nav menu without reloading the entire main view? something like templates or partial views. Is necesary to do this with ajax? How can it be? I don´t know much about ajax. It will be possible to see an example?

I load my home view in controller like this:

```
$data = [
            'header_view'               => 'main/header',
            'nav_view'                  => 'main/nav',
            'section_view'              => 'main/main_view',
            'article_view'              => 'main/article',
            'aside_view'                => 'main/aside',
            'footer_view'               => 'main/footer',
        ];

$this->load->view('home_view', $data);
```

Then I load the vievs from home view:

```
<section>  
            <?=$this->load->view($section_view);?>
</section>
...
```

And in the nav view I wanted to put the links to different sections without reload the nav view, because I will have a tree structure and other stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use AngularJS ? you can make a single page application using ui-routes or ng-routes. you can make ajax call to your controller method that will render your view, and you can show that view in  .

Comment: oh I didn't know AngularJS. I have just see many examples and I think it could work for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

In order to do a one page iframe site, you need to set up a controller to return a page without anything else

```
Controller -> loadpage($name)
```

then route it however you'd like

then, create an iframe with an id

```
<iframe name="maincontent"></iframe>
```

obviously, add in your needed styling / attributes.

On your links, add in targets

```
<a href="/url/page" target="maincontent">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: This will have the same problem about loading the entire page instead any section maintaining the rest.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, or give me a bit of a clearer example of what you want?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I have 3 views at the same time in my web. One of them have links to load content in the third view, but I don't want to change the content of first and second view. I have to reload only the content of the third one.

Comment: Can you do screenshots of before/afters of what you want? You're using terminology that I'm not understanding right.

Comment: I have just added one screen, but is not really complete. I will have textboxes on left side menu and more stuff.

Comment: AH, you don't want to reload the page but instead reloading a container in the page?

Comment: Yes that is what I need.

Comment: Replaced answer, that should do it :)

Comment: the problem is that I'm trying to do this without iframes because they're obsolete.

Comment: Then you could possibly use AJAX and jQuery and return the actual generated HTML from PHP.